# How to find the point with the maximum distance to its nearest neightbors in javascript

Tags: javascript, max, nearest-neighbor

I have a rectangular shaped area with a number of points on random positions in it. Now I want to place a new point at the position with the maximum distance to its nearest neighbors. A solution for the problem using SQL (and a polygonal shape) is given here: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/point-of-maximal-distance-queries-aka-variations-on-a-theme-of-nearest-neighbours/

But how can I do it in javascript?